# How can OpenCV cv::integral function allow summing of a rotated rectangular region in constant time?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

OpenCV [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga97b87bec26908237e8ba0f6e96d23e28) for `cv::integral` claims:

> Using these integral images, you can calculate sum, mean, and standard
> deviation over a specific up-right or **rotated rectangular** region of
> the image in a constant time

I can easily understand how the integral image can be used to compute the sum of an axis aligned rectangular region in constant time. As the documentation explains:

[image]

What I don't understand is how to use the same image to compute the sum over an arbitrarily rotated rectangular region in constant time.

The documentation seems to try to explain this, but I find it very hard to understand the diagrams and deduce a working algorithm / code that does this.

So how can one achieve this using opencv?

Comment: Does this help? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52038/how-can-i-sum-pixel-values-over-a-rotated-rectangle

Comment: There is a paper "The Fast Integration of a Rotated Rectangle 
Applied to the Rotated Haar-like Features for 
Rotated Objects Detection" but I didnt check what exactly is handled.

Comment: from my understanding, In OpenCV, the tiled image specifically means the 45 degree rotation. See the formula: [link](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga97b87bec26908237e8ba0f6e96d23e28)